# Issue with trying to convert an object to type int in python

Tags: python, string, error-handling, floating-point, int

I'm following the lectures from https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-2/lecture-10-hashing-and-classes/MIT6_00SCS11_lec10.pdf i'm looking at the code on the last page in the function readVal

and i'm trying to run the following code

```
val=input('type an int: ')
try:
    val=int(val)
    print(val)
except ValueError:
    print('not an int')
```

Now if i enter an integer say 2 everything is fine it prints 2. However if i enter an floating point number say 2.0 or a string '2' it raises an exception and prints the statement 'not an int', i find it confusing that it is not able to convert val to the appropriate type when it is 2.0 or '2' because if i run this piece of code

```
val = '2'
val = int(val) 
print(val)
```

Then i correctly get 2 without any problems. Why is this the case? I'd really appreciate any help as i'm keen to fully understand each piece of code i see. Thanks!

Comment: When you typing '2' it means that your val before casting to int equals "'2'". It's not an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different things you are doing. `input()` returns a string. Meaning if you type `2.0` it returns `"2.0"`. Python does not support this type of casting.

In your second example you directly set your variable to be a floating point or a string, which python is able to cast automatically to an integer.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out after when i tried type(val) before converting it and saw it was a string!!

Answer (score 3):

The `input` function produces values of string type. If you put 2 into your `input`, then you get 2 as a string to be converted to int. But if you put '2', then you'll get a string '2', which is not convertible to int anymore.

Have a look here: https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#numbers-and-strings-of-digits

Answer (score 1):

`val='2.0'` prints `"not an int. it's a float"`

`val='4'` is OK

`val='4a'` prints `"not an int. not a float either"`

`val="'4a"'` prints `"not an int. not a float either"` because it casts only once

```
val=input('type an int: ')
try:
    val=int(val)
    print(val)
except ValueError:
    print('not an int')
    try:
        val=float(val)
        print("it's a float")
    except ValueError:
        print("not a float either")
```

The `int()` function cannot cast a given string ([Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int))

Answer (score 1):

> However if i enter an floating point number say 2.0

If you type 2.0 at the input prompt, what python gets is `"2.0"` - a string composed of characters "2", "." and "0", which is not the same as the literal float `2.0`.

> or a string '2'

idem, if you type '2' at the input prompt, what python gets is the string `"'2'"` - that is, characters "'", "2" and "'".

Neither `"2.0"` nor `"'2'"` are valid string representations of an integer, so passing them to `int()` raises a `ValueError` indeed. If you absolutely insists on letting the user enter obviously invalid values and trying to make sense of them you will have to clean up the user inputs by yourself before passing them to `int()`.